# Make buttons stick to background image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently working on an interactive simulation with an image as a background. Like this:

```
<body>
  <div>
    <img><img>
    <button><button>
    <!-- etc.. -->
  <div>
<body>
```

Is it possible to make the buttons stick to the image when resizing the window. I've already tried things like setting the positions with a percentage instead of pixels etc. But nothing seems to work.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.container .btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container .btn:hover {
  background-color: black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Button on Image</h2>
<p>Add a button to an image:</p>

<div class="container">
  <img src="img_snow.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
  <button class="btn">Button</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you. But how do i make the text resize together with the button?

Comment: .text , button{
 font-size:22px;
}
Use a Class in text and add this CSS .This will change the button and text size together.And also remove font-size from ( .container .btn ).